# JavaScript Error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I need some help with this javascript code:
This is the error the page reports:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`.
This is the part of the js code that concerns it:

```
milano.onmouseover = VideoS;
milano.onmouseout = VideoF;
parigi.onmouseover = VideoS;
parigi.onmouseout = VideoF;
ny.onmouseover = VideoS;
ny.onmouseout = VideoF;
londra.onmouseover = VideoS;
londra.onmouseout = VideoF;
function VideoS() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'milano':
            video3.play();
            break
        case 'parigi':
            video4.play();
            break
        case 'ny':
            video5.play();
            break
        case 'londra':
            video6.play();
    }
}
function VideoF() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'milano':
            video3.pause();
            video3.currentTime = 0;
            break
        case 'parigi':
            video4.pause();
            video4.currentTime = 0;
            break
        case 'ny':
            video5.pause();
            video5.currentTime = 0;
            break
        case 'londra':
            video6.pause();
            video6.currentTime = 0;
    }
}
```

The functions work perfectly and do what they are supposed to do but the error that appears when I go over these divs containing videos I wish there wasn't a way to fix it? I noticed that by replacing onmouseover with onclick the error does not appear but I would like to maintain the interactivity of onmouseover

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the pause() was called while play() was being requested but hadn't been done yet. This is an error on the sense that the `play()` request had to terminate, but shouldn't be an obstacle to functioning code.

Comment: thx i will see those link Napoli was a batter name XD

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it by checking if the video is already playing before calling `play()`.

```js
function VideoS() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'milano':
            if (video3.paused) {
                video3.play();
            }
            break;
        case 'parigi':
            if (video4.paused) {
                video4.play();
            }
            break;
        case 'ny':
            if (video5.paused) {
                video5.play();
            }
            break;
        case 'londra':
            if (video6.paused) {
                video6.play();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is still not work i even tried with a variable 'check' that turn false when the video is paused and true when the video is playing and an if like if(check == true){ video4.play(); } but nothing i really dk